# Как в AJAX сделать GET запрос, чтобы url не менялся

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, get, axios

Есть задача, чтобы сделать `GET` запрос через `axios`, при том чтобы параметры не попадали в `url`, то бишь после запроса вместо `/catalog/rings/?PAGE=1`, сохранялся просто `/catalog/rings/`.

```js
async getData({
  state,
  commit
}, payload = {}) {
  const {
    options = {}, params = {}, method = 'get'
  } = payload;
  const req_url = `${window.location.pathname}?json=y`;
  await axios(req_url, {
      params,
    })
    .then((response) => {
      const {
        data
      } = response;

      if (options.merge === true) {
        commit('MERGE_ITEMS', data);
      } else {
        commit('SET_DATA', data);
        commit('SET_DATA_FILTERS', data);
      }
      commit('SET_STATUS', 'end');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
      commit('SET_STATUS', 'end');
    });
}
```

Comment: Приведите ваши попытки.

Comment: Попытки чего? запроса?

Comment: Ну конечно, так как я из вопроса не понял, что конкретно вы хотите сделать. Вы хотите находясь на странице `/catalog/rings` сделать запрос `/catalog/rings/?PAGE=1` методом `get`? Так если делать его через `axios` `url` не поменяется.

Comment: да, чтобы параметры не отображались  в url. ГРубо говоря, эмулируя POST

Comment: Вы не умеете пользоваться `axios`?

Comment: поверхностно. Умел бы на все сто, не спрашивал бы тут

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Axios` возвращает промис, поэтому в методе `then`(в случае успеха) работаем с данными (ответом), которые будут содержаться в `response`. В случае ошибки запроса результат промиса будет в `catch`

```js
axios.get('/catalog/rings/', {
  params: {
    page: 1,
    sort: 'asc',
    type: 'rock',
    // ...
  }
}).then((response) => {
  // do somthing
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Читайте документацию. На [гитхабе](https://github.com/axios/axios#example) отличный пример.

> UPD Параметры (у вас — `params`) — это *объект*. Пример передачи параметров в снипете или в `params` запишите данные `ключ:значение`.

Comment: Данный пример есть в документации в npm, и данные параметры добавляют в url параметры, собственно так я вызываю, только не через Промисс, а через async await

Comment: @AexFun,  вы что-то делаете не верно. Вы понимаете как работает `ajax`? Или, как я уже говорил, приведите ваш код. И вы точно понимаете чем отличается `get` от `post`?

Comment: Прошу прощения, да, действительно в голом варианте, он не добавляет в url параметры. А вот в моем проекте, видимо axios  настроен на это...Как тогда добавлять в url параметры?

Comment: Собственно, добавил сам метод из проекта.

Comment: @AexFun обновил ответ.

Comment: Всё, спасибо, я разобрался в чем причина